Question regarding integral representation of Dirac Delta function
I have a question regarding integral representation of Dirac delta function. The standard definition is:
$\delta(t-t')=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(t-t')\omega}d\omega$.
My question is: Is it possible to modify its definition as for example:
$\delta(t-t')=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{i(t-t')\omega}d\omega$
or
$\delta(t-t')=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{i(t-t')\omega}d\omega$

The Dirac delta is a distribution and not a normal function, so in what sense do you have this integral representation?

@Lorago. The first formula is (up to a factor) the distributional Fourier transform of a constant function. The Fourier transform of a distribution $u$ is defined by $\langle \mathcal{F}u, \varphi \rangle = \langle u, \mathcal{F}\varphi \rangle$ for all test functions $\varphi.$

The formulas you suggest are not valid. There will be an extra term.

No, your suggested formulas are not valid. Instead you have
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{it\omega} d\omega = \pi\delta(t) + \frac{i}{ t},
$$
where integrals over the last term are to be interpreted as principal value integrals.

It should be noted that this expression is more-or-less the Fourier transform of the Heaviside step function.

@JohnBarber. And I used $H'=\delta,$ and $\mathcal{F}{f'(t)}=i\omega\mathcal{F}{f(t)},$ and $\mathcal{F}{\delta}=1,$ to find the identity.

Your expression is not correct.  The factor $\frac1{2\pi}$ does not belong on the PV term; I've edited accordingly.  Also, given your convention $$\mathscr{F}{f'}=-i\omega \mathscr{F}{f}$$

@MarkViola. Thank you, friend! I must have got confused by the variables being swapped.

@md2perpe You're welcome.  My pleasure. And (+1)  I always enjoy reading your posts.  They are clear and concise and I have learned a lot from reading them.  Have a very Happy Holiday season my friend.
